How do I pass interfaces as an interfaces parameter
I am designing an application that reads and writes to a SQL Server database. I have multiple classes that are simply an instance of a table record (is this correctly called a model?) I want to create an interface (IDataModel) for the models to use.
I also want to create an interface (IDataModelUpdatable) that contains update method signatures to be implemented by those models that will update the database using IDataModel as the parameter types.
The problem I run into is that when I implement the IDataModelUpdatable methods, I cannot use the properties of the model because they are not in IDataModel. Each model has unique properties that need to be reference. It is my understanding that the purpose of Interfaces is to be able to interchange objects as long as they implement the same interface.
Is there a way to use IDataModel as the parameter, but reference the actual class's properties?
I have tried casting to the concrete class type, and even tried casting the concrete class to the interface type (IDataModel). None of it worked. I'm beginning to think that in order to used IDataModel as a parameter type, it will need all of the properties in order to reference them (which isn't feasible.
internal interface IDataModel 
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

internal interface IDataStoreUpdatable 
{
    void Update(IDataModel model);
    void Update(List<IDataModel> models);
}

public void Update(IDataModel bom)  
{
    transaction = new CommittableTransaction();
    string updateString = $@"UPDATE tblBOMs SET lngPalletSectionID = {bom.PalletSection.ID}, lngQuoteID = {bom.QuoteID}, strComponent = '{bom.Component}',
                                            bytQuantityNeeded = {bom.QuantityNeeded}, sngBDFT = {bom.BoardFeet} WHERE lngBOMID = {bom.ID}";

    OpenConnection();
    _sqlConnection.EnlistTransaction(transaction);
    // ....
}


You may be misunderstanding/misusing interfaces (and polymorphism in general).  If a method accepts an interface as a parameter then that method needs to be able to use any object which implements that interface, not just a specific one.  If the method needs a specific implementation, it should accept that implementation as a parameter.

If David's comment above isn't clear, or you would like some additional guidance, it might help if you could provide a small amount of code to illustrate what you want and what you've tried.

@David Yes, this is what I was afraid of. I am just learning to use interfaces, and was hoping there was a way to do what I wanted. I guess I'll just have to remember to include the CRUD functions in my classes (that's why I wanted to use an interface, so that it would force me to remember). Thanks.

@JamesDorsey: If the goal is just to enforce that a method is created then an interface can do that.  Arguably an abstract base class may be more suited to that specific task.  But the Update method should accept the specific implementing type and not the more generic interface or base class, since from the looks of the code shown each model will need its own custom Update method.

Usually, the model doesn't know how to operate the database. That's what ORMs and drivers are for. They come in various degrees of abstraction but basically, they would figure how to update from any model.

@David Yes, each model will need it's own custom parameter type, but I think I have figured out how to use the IDataModel. I created an interface for each model, each of which implements IDataModel. So now, when I pass in the IDataModel I can then cast to the specific interface model type I need to work with to access the properties. It does seem like a lot of interfaces, but isn't that what "Interface Segregation" about? I am not new to programming, but I am definitely an amateur when it comes to "proper" coding. I am just now learning about SOLID, which is why I am wanting to use interfaces.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!
